# How do log a user into Second Life from my own site?

Tags: linden-scripting-language

I have a site which manages the creation of Second Life  users for a particular island. Users will create a Second Life account through the site's RegAPI. However, their account information are not given to user, but instead store within a database. The requirement is that the user will log onto our site first (using our own authentication) and we'll automatically log their avatar into Second Life.

How do I send a request to log into Second Life from our site, and obtain a session id which we then pass to the user's viewer (through the secondlife::// protocol)

Comment: you also need to watch the terms of service, there are some rules governing handling of other people's SL user authentication data.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the idea of having a web login key returned to a server and using that to log users in through the viewer has been dropped. The only way I see is to modify the Second Life viewer code to take in the avatar name and password through SLURL (preferably encrypted first).

Answer (score 0):

Second life uses a openid authentication scheme and oauth. The best model would to have users register viva openid/oauth to linden labs then present them with a secondlife:// uri links.
ie:

```
secondlife://app/login?first=%USERFNAME%&last=%USERLNAME%&session=%SECURESESSIONIDFROMOPENID%&location=%RegionXYZ%
```